# relation of eigenvalue of cross product and weighted cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I have a matrix $X$ that is, say $n\times p$ and a diagonal matrix $W$ $n\times n$ with all positive values on the diagonal, is there a relationship between the eigenvalues of $X^TX$ and $X^TWX$? or a relationship between the eigenvalues of $X^TWX$ and those of $X^TX$ and/or $W$?

In addition are there any upper and lower bounds for the eigenvalues of $X^TWX$?

In particular I am only interested in the above for the largest eigenvalue, not necessarily all of them